# Python: function that exclude negative values from list and give back new list

Tags: python, function

I have list of numbers.
I must using function exclude negative values and the positive add to new list.

I know how to do that with for loop but when I try to add there function it does not work for me.
Could you please suggest something.

This is the code which is working but it's loop:

```
new_list = []
for i in data:
    if i > 0:
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

This function does not work. It gives me None.

```
data2 = [10, 32, 454, 31, -3, 53, -31, -54, -9594, 31314, 53, 10]


def preprocessing(data):
    new_list = []
    for i in data:
        if i > 0:
            return new_list.append(i)

preprocessing(data2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple comprehension:

```
data3 = [i for i in data2 if i > 0]
print(data3)

# Output
[10, 32, 454, 31, 53, 31314, 53, 10]
```

For your function, `data.append` return nothing so you return `None`:

```
def preprocessing(data):
    new_list = []
    for i in data:
        if i > 0:
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list  # <- HERE
```

Usage:

```
data3 = preprocessing(data2)
print(data3)

# Output
[10, 32, 454, 31, 53, 31314, 53, 10]
```

Comment: Sure, I've just did it :)

Answer (score 2):

Your function `prepocessing` returns None because you call the return too early.

`append()` is a method of the list object that modifies the object and returns nothing. So when you return the result of this method, it returns `None`.

You could simply do this:

```py
def preprocessing(data):
    new_list = []
    for i in data:
        if i > 0:
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Corralien already gave good answers but I feel one is missing. To create an iterable which contains only >0 from data2:

```
new_iter = filter(lambda x: x > 0, data2)
```

Using an iterable may be advantageous in circumstances where you are later looping through the list but maybe not all of it. This way the list is only evaluated as far as you need it.

To turn it into a list, just do `new_list = list(new_iter)`.